# What folders to include?

Tags: android, image, performance, directory, pixel

Although I want my application to be supported by multiple screen sizes, I don't want to have one million image resource directories for no reason. **So, what are the image directories that I should include** based on the amount of devices that use them. For example, I was told that `mdpi` and `ldpi` are obsolete to use now. This information is not easily found, so I am lost as to what directories to use, and what to size my images based on them.  I have spent the last 5 and a half hours resizing images and adding them to different directories, and am confused on which directories I even need to add the images to...

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Answer (score 2):

> So, what are the image directories that I should include based on the amount of devices that use them.

You include the directories where you need pre-scaled images to give you quality results.

Suppose that you have an image in `res/drawable-hdpi/foo.png`, and that is the only copy of `foo.png` in your project. When you test your app on devices, see what `foo` looks like. Android will be automatically re-scaling `foo` so that it is approximately the same size on the screen you are testing as it would be on an `-hdpi` screen. Sometimes, Android's automatic re-scaling does an OK job. Sometimes, it does not. If you determine that it does not, you would create other editions of `foo`, at relevant densities, so you control what the re-scaled image looks like.

However, only you can judge for your app what you need. And only you can decide what densities you will procure hardware for to use in testing.

> For example, I was told that mdpi and ldpi are obsolete to use now. This information is not easily found...

Well, the information about what percentage of devices use different screen densities is part of [the device dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens).

There is no such thing as an "obsolete" density. At most, you might say that a density is currently unpopular. `-ldpi` — sitting at 2.9% in the January 2016 dashboards — is currently unpopular overall. It may be more relevant for you and your app, though, depending on where you expect your user base to come from. Also, those dashboards are for the Play ecosystem; devices that lie outside of that (Amazon Kindle Fire, most devices in China, etc.) will have different characteristics.